# I cant login after update ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, login

I have some trouble when updating with `dist-upgrade` on Ubuntu 14.04. Actually I just want update my 14.04 into the newest one but after updating, this error message appears **cant start Ubuntu session**. 
After following some instructions on the internet, finally right now my Ubuntu is stuck at login screen with the following error message *(please see from screenshot for more detail)*

Thanks in advance, any support will be appreciated.

[image: stuck into login screen]

[image: stuck into recovery mode also]

Comment: you broke your `init` system, maybe `systemd`. try to boot from an external medium, like an USB drive. check, if `/sbin/init` exitst and check the destination of `/sbin/init`, it should be `/bin/systemd`.

Comment: from live cd you mean ? can I fix this without re-install maybe ?

Comment: It may be possible to fix this without reinstallation. Try to check your init environment with a live cd.

Comment: Hi littlebyblue , could you gime a guidance script to check init system , right know im using ubuntu 16.04 live cd

Comment: log in as root `sudo su -`; check if `/sbin/init` exists and what it actually is: `ls -l /sbin/init` (it should be `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Apr 12 12:34 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd`